# mouse cursor change based on event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have an ajax request that I'm sending. When the request starts, I have

```
  document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
```

which immediately changes the appearance of the cursor to a spinning circle.

When the request ends, I have

```
  document.body.style.cursor = "default";
```

However, this only returns the cursor to its original state when the user moves the mouse; if the mouse stays still, the cursor won't change. When you set it to "auto" or any other kind, the cursor change will only trigger when it moves.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just scroll window by 0,0.

```
document.body.style.cursor = "auto";
window.scroll(0, 0);
// tested in IE8 and FF3.6
```

And when the request ends, you need to set cursor to "auto", not a "default". You can see the difference on any element with text.

Comment: Googled about that and found numerous grumps, that Chrome have problems with cursor update even in _normal_ situations, w/o any javascript.

Comment: @kirilloid As far as I can tell, this doesn't work in IE9 either. Did it work for you?

Comment: @Jayraj There were no IE9 when I tested that. I don't have OS suitable for IE9 and don't want to mess with VMs, therefore I'll just believe you it don't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's a chrome bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26723