# Spinning Cursor (Thobber) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor

**Hello,**
I like to display a spining thobber-like cursor while validating a Form on the server side.

Do you have any other (better) suggestions ?

I have found this, but how to add it to the cursor ?
http://aino.github.com/throbber.js/

Best Regards
Marc

Comment: Start the cursor function, send form via ajax, upon ajax response stop cursor function.

Comment: Yeah thats clear, but how to add a spinning cursor while processing? Any Fiddle would be awesome please

Answer (score 0):

this could be another option, it will be displayed in the center of the form or element that you set.
http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/

you can configure the look of the spinner in  spin.js and is really easy to use.

If you need the cursor to be changed the I think this may help
[mouse cursor change based on event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988016/mouse-cursor-change-based-on-event#)

Comment: Looks great , but wht if when the cenyter of my form is not visible on the screen? Is there a way to append it to my cursor ? or surround it ?

Comment: the spinner will show on top of the element that you select, lets say that you have a form and when you submit you hide the form, then perhaps it will be better to append the spinner to the container of the form.

Comment: If you need the cursor to be changed the I think this may help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988016/mouse-cursor-change-based-on-event#)